# how to redirect index.php in fat-free framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I re-wrote my old app in fat-free framework. Everybody who used this app have bookmark http://www.domain/app/index.php This url now does not work in F3.
Can I redirect index.php to http://www.domain/app/ ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the redirection at the [framework level](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/base#redirect):

- either in your `index.php` file:

```php
$f3->redirect('GET /index.php','/');
```

- or in your config file:

```
[redirects]
GET /index.php = /
```

Comment: OK. I thought I could not redirect index.php because of definition in htaccess
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]`